# Error 2448 can't assign value to field/control

Tags: vba, ms-access, field

I am attempting to simply retrieve data from one form and fill in a field on a different form so that when I create a new record in a database, certain information will be retained.

I would like to have something like `Me.AlbumID = albumNumber` where `albumNumber` is a variable that stores the value from the other form, but I keep getting error 2448 saying that I cannot assign a value to this field.

I've tried a multiplicity of different syntax changes and tried erasing the binding in the control box, which is just a text box, but can't seem to figure out what the issue is.  I imagine it's probably fairly simple, but so far I'm stuck.

Currently I have (written in vba):

```
Private Sub AddTracksButton_Click()
    Dim albumNumber As Integer
    albumNumber = Me.AlbumID
    DoCmd.OpenForm "TracksEditor", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    Me.AlbumID = albumNumber
End Sub
```

The value gets assigned and carried over to the new form just fine, e.g. 1 or 2 and so on, but the problem is that then applying a line that looks like `Me.AlbumID = albumNumber` throws the error 2448.  The control is bound to the field because ideally I'd like to be editing the field directly.

Advice?

Answer (score 0):

This actually ended up working, I wrote in SQL to access the database directly instead of trying to go through the from.  It turns out you can make it look like this and it will work:

```
Private Sub AddTracksButton_Click()
    Dim albumNumber As Integer
    albumNumber = Me.AlbumID
    DoCmd.OpenForm "TracksEditor", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "INSERT INTO Tracks (AlbumID) VALUES (" & albumNumber & ")"
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
End Sub
```

I hope this helps someone else.